# Encoding issue, failing with Assertion Error

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding, charset

I have a class with a function as follows
`

```
    private static Path compileNamedModuleTest() throws IOException {
        Path base = Paths.get(".", "named");
        Path src = base.resolve("src");
        Path classes = base.resolve("classes");

        ModuleInfoMaker maker = new ModuleInfoMaker(src);
        maker.writeJavaFiles("test",
                              "module test {}",
                              "package test; public sealed interface Base permits test.a.ImplA1, test.a.ImplA2, test.b.ImplB, test.c.ImplC {}",
                              "package test.a; public final class ImplA1 implements test.Base {}",
                              "package test.a; public final class ImplA2 implements test.Base {}",
                              "package test.b; public final class ImplB implements test.Base {}",
                              "package test.c; public final class ImplC implements test.Base {}"
                              );
        
         System.out.println("Default Charset: "
                           + Charset.defaultCharset());
                           
        if (!CompilerUtils.compile(src, classes.resolve("test"), "--enable-preview", "-source", System.getProperty("java.specification.version"))) {
            throw new AssertionError("Compilation didn't succeed!");
        }

        Files.delete(classes.resolve("test").resolve("test").resolve("c").resolve("ImplC.class"));

        return classes;
    }
```

`

and `WriteJavaFiles` function as

```
    /**
     * Create java source files of the given module
     */
    public void writeJavaFiles(String module, String moduleInfoJava, String... contents)
        throws IOException
    {
        Path msrc = dir.resolve(module);
        new JavaSource(moduleInfoJava).write(msrc);
        for (String c : contents) {
            new JavaSource(c).write(msrc);
        }
    }
```

I am getting error as Error:

> Java files created during execution have encoding issues due to which
> compilation fails.
>
> ```
> ./named/src/test/test/a/ImplA1.java:1: error: illegal character: '\u009b'
> /named/src/test/test/a/ImplA2.java:1: error: illegal character: '\u0080'
> ```

Which I believe is an encoding issue and need to add `charset.defaultCharset()` somewhere. But I am unsure where to put it?

JavaSource class

```
static class JavaSource {
        final String source;
        JavaSource(String source) {
            this.source = source;
        }

        /**
         * Writes the source code to a file in a specified directory.
         * @param dir the directory
         * @throws IOException if there is a problem writing the file
         */
        public void write(Path dir) throws IOException {
            Path file = dir.resolve(getJavaFileNameFromSource(source));
            Files.createDirectories(file.getParent());
            try (BufferedWriter out = Files.newBufferedWriter(file)) {
                out.write(source.replace("\n", System.lineSeparator()));
            }
        }
```

I tried adding `Charset` as argument in `WriteJavaFiles` but did not help.

Comment: What is the `JavaSource` class?  What does its `write` method look like?

Comment: @VGR I have added it in the question. Thank you.

Comment: [The documentation for Files.newBufferedWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedWriter(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.OpenOption...)) clearly says it uses UTF-8.  You should pass `"-encoding", "UTF-8"` to your CompilerUtils.compile method.

Comment: so, I should specify encoding as  try (BufferedWriter out = Files.newBufferedWriter(file, Charset.defaultCharset()))

Comment: **Caution:** As of Java 18, [defaultCharset() always returns UTF-8 on all platforms.](https://openjdk.org/jeps/400)  I strongly recommend using UTF-8 both for the files and for the compiler.  It’s the easiest, most portable way to be certain the program works everywhere.